# issues with testing authorization in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, authorization

I am trying to implement Railscasts authorization from scratch in my own app, however I am having a simple issue with custom matchers and testing. I am getting a wrong number of arguments error and I can't seem to figure out why.

I created a separate Permission model to hold all of the logic and in this model there is an `allow?` method. This is where all of the logic would be. I tested it manually through the browser and it works however my unit tests fail due to wrong number of arguments

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

This is the permission model

```
class Permission < Struct.new(:user)
  def allow?(controller, action)
    return true if controller == 'sessions'
    return true if controller == 'users' && action.in?(%w[new create])
    if user && user.teams.nil?
      return true if controller == 'users' && action.in?(%w[new index show edit update])
      return true if controller == 'teams' && action.in?(%w[new create index])
      return true if controller == 'user_teams' && action.in?(%w[index])
    elsif user && !user.teams.nil?
      return true if controller == 'users' && action.in?(%w[index show edit update])
      return true if controller == 'teams' && action.in?(%w[new create index show])
      return true if controller == 'user_teams' && action.in?(%w[index])
      return true if controller == 'texts' && action.in?(%w[new create index show])
      return true if controller == 'translations' && action.in?(%w[show])

    end
  end
end
```

here is the code for the custom matcher located in `spec/support/matchers/allow.rb`

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :allow do |*args|
  match do |permission|
    permission.allow?(*args).should be_true
  end

  failure_message_for_should do |permission|
    "expected to have permission for these actions"
  end

  failure_message_for_should_not do |permission|
    "expected to not have permission for these actions"
  end

  description do 
    "allow access to the %{*args} actions"
  end
end
```

Here is my application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authorize
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper
  include UserTeamsHelper

  add_flash_types :success, :danger 

  private

  def current_permission
    @current_permission ||= Permission.new(current_user)
  end

  def authorize
    if !current_permission.allow?(params[:controller], params[:action])
      redirect_to root_url, danger: 'Önce Giriş Yapmalısınız'
    end
  end

end
```

And here is the test for the Permission model

```
require "spec_helper"

describe Permission do 
  describe 'as a non user' do 
    subject { Permission.new(nil) } 
    it { should allow("sessions", "new") } 
  end
end
```

But it does not work because I am getting a wrong number of arguments error. Can someone point me on the right path of testing these?

Here is the test failure I am getting

```
Failures:

  1) Permission as a non user
     Failure/Error: it { should allow("sessions", "new") }
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
     # ./spec/models/permission_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.07471 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/permission_spec.rb:6 # Permission as a non user
```

Comment: Can't you post a stack trace so we can know exactly which line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allow` is an RSpec method defined in https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/fd78578d0d65a7917701c4410a0eb9089ee6636f/lib/rspec/mocks/syntax.rb which takes one parameter. That's why you're getting this error.

You can verify this by executing the following example:

```
describe "RSpec allow method" do
  it "should exist" do
    puts method(:allow)
    puts method(:allow).source_location
  end
end
```

which should generate something like:

```
#<Method: RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1(RSpec::Mocks::ExampleMethods)#allow>
/Users/palfvin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@botmetrics/gems/rspec-mocks-2.14.3/lib/rspec/mocks/syntax.rb 117
```

If you use a different matcher name, I would think you'd be ok.